# Google Apps Script (GAS)における特定文字列を含む行の抜き出し

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートの１列目にある特定の文字列を含むものだけを取り出すコードを作っているのですがうまくいきません。
ご指摘いただければ助かります。

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(let i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var str = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    console.log(str.match(/{特定文字の正規表現}/g));
  }
}
```

Comment: 交換してみましたか`str.match();` と `str.includes();` ？

Comment: trueのprintstrを返す場合

Comment: エラーを送ってくれませんか

Comment: @SeaverOlson 
ありがとうございます。交換してもエラーがでます。
{特定文字の正規表現}の部分には「+円+」を入れていて、円が含まれる行を抜き出したいです。

Comment: 構文エラー: ParseError: Invalid regular expression 行: 7 ファイル: コード.gs
上記がエラーです。

Comment: 正規表現を「+」→「.*」に変えたらうまくいきました。失礼しました

Answer (score 1):

正規表現が間違っていたようで、正規表現の項目で「+」→「.*」に変えたらうまくいきました。